# Jenkins Gerrit Trigger plugin's feature "Block build until replication is complete" dose not work

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I want to pull code from Gerrit slave, there is a feature of Jenkins Gerrit Trigger plugin called "Block build until replication is complete",  But it seems not work, I found my build always start immediately, but not wait the replciation done. Below is my configuration.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just re-installed my jenkins, and it works.